# Merging inherited class's variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to merge a dictionary of a subclass with class inheritance

```
class Person(object):
    nametag = {
        "name": "Bob",
        "occupation": "Nobody"
    }

class Teacher(Person):
    nametag = {
        "occupation": "Professor",
        "Subject": "Python"
    }

    def __init__(self):
        nametag = dict(Person.nametag.items() + self.nametag.items())
```

Ultimately I need:

```
Teacher().nametag["name"] == "bob"
Teacher().nametag["occupation"] == "Professor"
Teacher().nametag["subject"] == "Python"
```

Side note, `Teacher.nametag` and `Person.nametag` are going to be very large dictionaries, is `dict(d2.keys() + d1.keys())` the best way to do it?

Comment: Why aren't these instance variables?

Comment: Make them instance variables and do `self.nametag.update(super().nametag)` in the child class.

Comment: The reason they weren't instances was because I thought it would be more easily readable, but I'm happy with anything

Comment: It's not about readability; class attributes are the same for all instances of the class, instance attributes can be different for each instance. Unless all `Teacher`s will be called `"Bob"`, it's not an ideal fit!

Comment: That makes much more sense. Thanks "Bob"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, each *instance* of your various classes is going to have a different `nametag`. Therefore, the best implementation is not the class attribute dictionary you currently have, but instance attributes:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, occupation):
        self.name = name
        self.occupation = occupation

class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, occupation, subject):
        super().__init__(name, occupation)
        self.subject = subject

bob = Teacher("Bob", "Professor", "Python")
bob.name == "Bob"
```

If you actually need the `nametag`, you could implement it as:

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name, occupation):
        self.name = name
        self.occupation = occupation

    @property
    def nametag(self):
        return {"name": self.name,
                "occupation": self.occupation}

class Teacher(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, occupation, subject):
        super().__init__(name, occupation)
        self.subject = subject

    @property
    def nametag(self):
        tag = super().nametag
        tag["subject"] = self.subject
        return tag

bob = Teacher("Bob", "Professor", "Python")
bob.nametag["name"] == "Bob"
```

As a side note,

```
dict(d2.keys() + d1.keys())
```

Will give you an error. To combine two dictionaries, do:

```
d1.update(d2)
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle the original case, though? Specifically, if you don't want to instantiate an object of the class in order to access it's class members?

Comment: @NathanielFord please give more context; the short answer is yes, but why?

Comment: My case is that I have an arbitrary list of classes, all of which are children of a common parent class, and possibly intermediate parents, each which will have some information (stored as a class member) indicating what they need to run. I need to go check each class, get it's info and that of all it's parents, to verify that it can remain in my list - but I need it before I instantiate any of the classes. Does that make sense?

Comment: I posted this as a full question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835312/merging-class-members

Answer (score 0):

If the nametags need to be properties of Person and Teacher, then pulling them out as separate classes that inherit from each other will work (think database foreign keys):

```
class PersonNametag(object):
    name = 'Bob'
    occupation = 'Nobody'


class TeacherNametag(PersonNametag):
    occupation = 'Professor'
    Subject = 'Python'


class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nametag = PersonNametag()


class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nametag = TeacherNametag()
```