# Merging Class Members

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Given a class structure like this:

```
class A:
    dependencies = ["x", "y"]

class B(A):
    dependencies = ["z"]

class C(A):
    dependencies = ["n", "m"]

class D(C):
    dependencies = ["o"]
```

I want to know if it's possible to write a function (preferably living on class A) that does something along these lines:

```
@classmethod
def get_all_dependencies(cls):
    return super().get_all_dependencies() + cls.dependencies
```

For the above classes, the expected output would be:

```
>>> A.get_all_dependencies():
["x", "y"]
>>> B.get_all_dependencies():
["x", "y", "z"]
>>> C.get_all_dependencies():
["x", "y", "n", "m"]
>>> D.get_all_dependencies():
["x", "y", "n", "m", "o"]
```

Obviously the above code doesn't work - it just returns the `dependencies` of the class I call it on. I'm not sure how to get it to work recursively across all the classes? (I'm eliding a `hasattr` check to ensure the parent class call `get_all_dependencies()`.)

Comment: To the close-vote: not sure how this is too broad? I've defined a minimally reproducible example. Can you explain what needs to be improved in the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Walk the `mro` and grab the dependencies is what I'd do:

```
@classmethod
def get_dep(cls):
    return [d for c in cls.mro()[:-1] for d in getattr(c, 'dependencies')]
```

with `cls.mro()[:-1]` being used to exclude `object`.

This returns:

```
>>> A.get_dep()
['x', 'y']
>>> B.get_dep()
['z', 'x', 'y']
>>> C.get_dep()
['n', 'm', 'x', 'y']
>>> D.get_dep()
['o', 'n', 'm', 'x', 'y']
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I didn't know about the MRO.

Answer (score 4):

Walk the MRO manually:

```
@classmethod
def get_all_dependencies(cls):
    deps = []
    for c in cls.__mro__:
        # Manual dict lookup to not pick up inherited attributes
        deps += c.__dict__.get('dependencies', [])
    return deps
```

If you want to deduplicate dependencies that appear repeatedly in the MRO, you can:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

@classmethod
def get_all_dependencies(cls):
    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(dep for c in cls.__mro__
                                         for dep in c.__dict__.get('dependencies', [])))
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about the mro - that solves all my problems!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this if you define "get_all_dependencies" on each class and, instead of `cls.dependencies`, you reference the class that you're on (ie. `super(B, self).get_all_dependences() + B.dependencies`)